# Steps to diagnose Bazel slowness

Tags: profiling, bazel

I am experiencing a long 'clean build' time using Bazel in my current project.

What are the steps we recommend steps to diagnose this?

Answer (score 7):

Try to profile your build with [`--profile`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--profile)

The syntax is `bazel build --profile file //my:target`

Then you can get a summary of the profiling information with `bazel analyze-profile file` and comprehensive chart of executed task with `bazel analyze-profile --html file`